# Spring Data and MongoDB - join a document with an embedded one

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have two documents in my appl:

```
@Document(collection = "Institution")
public class Institution {

...

// its an embedded document
private Address address;

...
```

and the Address ducument looks like this:

```
@Document(collection = "Address")
public class Address {

...

private ProvinceTypeEnum district;

...
```

I would need a @Query where I get all Institutions of a district. 
Is there a way of doing this with @Query(...) and how. I have tried a few queries but I have the problem with the embedded document. e.g I have tried this but I don not get any institution:

```
public interface InstitutionRepository extends MongoRepository<Institution, String> {

@Query(value = "{ 'institution.district' : ?0 }")
Set<Institution> findInstitutionByDistrict(final ProvinceTypeEnum district);
}
```